# Using C#, how do I access a COM dispinterface in an exe? (MissingMethodException)

Tags: c#, c++, com

First of all I apologise in advance if I don't explain my question properly due to my lack of knowledge.

I'm attempting to call a method from my C# program on an executable written in C++ that has a COM interface.

Unfortunately I can't make changes to the C++ but I do have access to the source for reference

The interface looks like:

```cpp
    [ uuid(369AF225-D0F4-11D8-9DF3-00A0C91D6277), version(1.0) ]
    library Spares
    {
        importlib("stdole32.tlb");
        importlib("stdole2.tlb");

        [ uuid(369AF226-D0F4-11D8-9DF3-00A0C91D6277) ]
        dispinterface ISpares
        {   
            methods:
                [id(1)] void SetTaskId(BSTR TaskId);
                [id(2)] boolean ReplaceLRU(long HotspotVal);
                [id(3)] void SetUsingToolkit(boolean UsingToolkit);
        };

        [ uuid(369AF224-D0F4-11D8-9DF3-00A0C91D6277) ]
        coclass Spares
        {
            [default] dispinterface ISpares;
        };
    };
```

And my code looks like:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace COMTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Process[] sparesProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Spares");

                if (0 == sparesProcess.Length)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Spares.exe not found");
                    return;
                }

                Type replaceLRUType = sparesProcess[0].GetType();
                object replaceLRUResult = replaceLRUType.InvokeMember("ReplaceLRU", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, sparesProcess[0], new object[]{(long)373145380});
                Console.WriteLine(replaceLRUResult.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

My code gives me a MissingMethodException but I don't know enough about COM to google the answer. How can I call ReplaceLRU?

Comment: You can't create a COM object like this. Try that instead: `dynamic p=Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("369AF224-D0F4-11D8-9DF3-00A0C91D6277")));p.ReplaceLRU(whatever);` Have a look at the C# `dynamic` keyword, it's super useful for COM IDispatch calls.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thank you for the response.
I've tried something similar without any luck.
I followed your example and got a RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Comment: It's not working because your COM class doesn't implement `IDispatch` - you won't be able to call methods by name without that.  Did you try adding a reference via the  normal Add Reference menu in Visual Studio - that should generate the classes and interfaces you need.

Comment: Thanks shf301. Is that not more for a dll rather than calling something on an exe?
Admittedly I'm a VSCode user so I'm not familiar with it but I've just installed VS 2019 and followed what you said and I get an error "The reference is invalid or unsupported"